# A for loop not doing as expected

Tags: php

I am running a for loop and attempting to enter data into an array.

When I run the print_r of the array, it's as if the for loop is only running once when it should be running multiple times!

```
for($i=0; $i<count($count); $i++){
        $currentField = $array[$i];
        $test = "".$field."[".$i."]";
        $this->_postData[$test] = $currentField;
        $this->_currentItems[$i] = $test;
    }

    print_r($this->_currentItems);
    die();
```

If I echo $count before, it says 3 (for example) but still when I print the array, it only has 1 value! Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: put your whole code AND data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be some silly logical error. I've looked at it for too long, oh dear me! Thanks though!

Comment: The longer detail of this answer is: count() was correctly returning the length of your non-array variable, which is 1.

Comment: Of course, I understand that :) I had copy and pasted a bit of code from elsewhere and couldn't spot the issue!

Answer (score 1):

i think  count is not needed .

try

```
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
```